# Wordpress change author email notify message?

Tags: customization, functions

just want to change a little bit author email notify message(wp_notify_postauthor - pluggable.php),and I'm applying filters on comment_notification_text

```
function myfunction(){
  return "<div class='left_side'>"..$comment..$post.."</div>"
}

add_filter('comment_notification_text', 'myfunction');
```

How to access data $comment,$post,... in myfunction ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$comment_id can be passed as second parameter to your function.

Modify you add_filter:

```
add_filter('comment_notification_text', 'myfunction', 10, 2);
```

Then get $comment and $post from $comment_id:

```
function myfunction( $notify_message, $comment_id ) {
    $comment = get_comment( $comment_id );
    $post    = get_post($comment->comment_post_ID);
```